# Adding Variables to CLASSPATH Java

Tags: java, classpath

I'm trying to add OnBarcode.AndroidBarcode.jar to the class path in windows. I've set a new environment variable called CLASSPATH and put the path to the jdk bin folder in it. 
I've put OnBarcode.AndroidBarcode.jar in that bin folder. I've also put OnBarcode.AndroidBarcode.jar in  the libs folder in my project. And thats it. It doesn't work.

I've already looked at a couple of other posts like http://tinyurl.com/krs9w3b

Comment: You need to specify the complete path (including the filename) to the jar files in the `CLASSPATH`, not the folder name.

Comment: Even if I do specify the jar file itself, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the contents of a directory but you need to add a wildcard. Assuming you are using java 6+.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29

Adding all JAR files in a directory

In Java 6 and higher, one can add all jar-files in a specific directory to the classpath using wildcard notation.

Windows example:

java -classpath ".;c:\mylib*" MyApp

Linux example:

java -classpath '.:/mylib/*' MyApp

This works for both -classpath options and environment classpaths.